# Change Android L+ keyboard color to dark

Tags: android, keyboard

I am using some EditText views in my android application. And all the design is dark. So white android lollipop keyboard doesn't look very cool. Is it possible to change keyboard color scheme to dark? I know this feature in iOS, but what about Android?

I would be thankful to you for any help!

Comment: Create a custom keyboard

Comment: @Apurva is that the only option?

Comment: You cannot change the android keyboard color, either change your activity ui or create another keyboard